# What is difference between following two format() methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are these two format() methods are different? If so, then how can i know which class they belong to and how they behave differently?

```
format('abc')
```

and

```
'abc'.format()
```

Comment: I can't think of a use for either, as posted, so that unites them

Answer (score 2):

Your first snippet uses the `format` built-in function, documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) for the built-in functions. Your second snippet uses `str.format`, a method of the `str` class, documented in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for the standard types. These are closely related, but the correspondence doesn't quite work the way you have things.

`format(thing, 'format_spec')` is equivalent to `'{:format_spec}'.format(thing)`. The format spec defaults to an empty string, so `format(thing)` is equivalent to `'{:}'.format(thing)`, which is usually equivalent to `str(thing)`.

`format('abc')` corresponds to `'{}'.format('abc')`, not `'abc'.format()`. The results happen to be equivalent because `'abc'` is a string with no format placeholders in it. If you had used `'I love braces{}'` or `3` instead of `'abc'`, you would have seen different behavior.